# Preparing multiple serial ports with multiple TCP in my project that I can enable or disable if I want

Tags: programming-practices

I have intermediate level of understanding on how TCP and serial works, I've also been able to develop system that uses

1. 1 TCP client and 1 Serial
2. 2 Serials
3. 1 TCP Server
4. 1 TCP client

My problem is that whenever I am creating a new project there are different needs, sometimes it's 1 TCP client and 1 Serial, sometimes it is 5 serials.

Right now I am thinking whether preparing 5 serial, 5 TCP client and 1 Server that can be enabled or disabled depending on my projects need is reliable? Preparing 5 seems too much, but I want to prepare it so whenever there is a need I can quickly activate them.

Some suggested that by using class I can do the same. I never use classes, I can study it but the question is do I really need it or is there a best way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

wrapping each connection in an instance (of a class) allows for easily caching partial messages, thus allowing a single-threaded model to handle all the communications tasks without blocking. (assuming you can figure out how to do non-bloking reads and writes) by being single threaded you avoid the synchronization problems that can plague multi-threaded code.

Comment: Why the down-vote?